# How to remove line if it contains a character exactly once

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I want to remove a line from a file which contains a particular character only once, if it is present more than once or is not present then keep the line in file.

For example:

```
DTHGTY
FGTHDC
HYTRHD
HTCCYD
JUTDYC
```

Here, the character which I want to remove is `C` so, the command should remove lines `FGTHDC` and `JUTDYC` because they have `C` exactly once.

How can I do this using either `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 20):

In `awk` you can set the field separator to anything. If you set it to `C`, then you'll have as many fields +1 as occurrences of `C`.

So if you say `awk -F'C' '{print NF}' <<< "C1C2C3"` you get `4`: `CCC` consists in 3 `C`s, and hence 4 fields.

You want to remove lines in which `C` occurs exactly once. Taking this into consideration, in your case you will want to remove those lines in which there are exactly two `C`-fields. So just skip them:

```
$ awk -F'C' 'NF!=2' file
DTHGTY
HYTRHD
HTCCYD
```

Comment: Astute use of `awk` field separator !

Comment: interresting, as in the default case (FS=" ") it ignores leading spaces ($1 = the first non-space on the line) and also repetitions (you can have 5 spaces to separate field 1 and field 2) ... space is probably treated specially? (to see it, one can do `awk 'BEGIN { print "FS={" FS"}","OFS={" OFS "}";} {printf "%d fields : ",NF; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "{" $i "} ";}; print "" }'` and feed it some lines, some having multiple spces, and others begininng with space(s))

Comment: @OlivierDulac, yes, space is handled specially [as specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04).

Answer (score 8):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i '/^[^C]*C[^C]*$/d' input
```

---

`-i` option allows in-place file modification

`/^[^C]*C[^C]*$/` - matches lines that contain `C` only once

`d` - delete matched lines

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with `sed` as:

**Code:**

```
sed '/C.*C/p;/C/d' file1
```

**Results:**

```
DTHGTY
HYTRHD
HTCCYD
```

**How?**

1. Match and print any line with at least two copies of `C` via `/C.*C/p`
2. Delete any line with a `C` via `/C/d`, this includes the lines already printed in step 1
3. Default print the rest of the lines

Comment: Clever alternative approach; I like it.

Answer (score 6):

This removes the lines with exactly one occurrence of C.

```
grep -v '^[^C]*C[^C]*$' file
```

The regular expression `[^C]` matches one character which isn't C (or newline), and the repetition operator (aka Kleene star) `*` specifies zero or more repetitions of the preceding expression.

The default output from `grep` (and most other text-oriented tools) is to standard output; redirect to a new file and maybe move it on top of the original file if that's what you want.  The same regex can be used with `sed -i` for in-place editing:

```
sed -i '/^[^C]*C[^C]*$/d' file
```

(On some platforms, notably *BSD including macOS, the `-i` option requires an argument, like `-i ''`.)

Comment: `sed -i '/^[^C]*C[^C]*$/d' file` - sounds like it was posted before, how do you think, plagiarism?

Comment: Indeed, there is some duplication.  I started out with the `grep` answer but it obviously easily extends to the `sed -i` variant.  Didn't see your answer because I was looking for previous `grep` answers.

Comment: It's safer to just plainly avoid `-i` with `sed` and instead redirect to a new file and replace the original with that if the `sed` utility exited with no error.

Comment: Or `grep -vx '[^C]*C[^C]*'`

Comment: @Kusalananda But then you might as well use `grep` because it's clearer and more robust (in particular, `sed` has a less informative exit code).

Comment: @tripleee In this case, yes maybe.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX tool for scripted edits of a file (rather than printing the modified contents to standard out) is `ex`.

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^[^C]*C[^C]*$/d' x | ex file.txt
```

Of course you can [use `sed -i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362551/135943) if your version of Sed supports it, just be aware that's not portable if you're writing a script that's intended to run on different types of systems.

---

David Foerster asked in the comments:

> Is there a reason why you're using `printf` and not `echo` or something like `ex -c COMMAND`?

Answer: Yes.

For `printf` vs. `echo` it's a question of portability; see [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)  And it's also easier to intersperse newlines between commands using `printf`.

For `printf ... | ex` vs. `ex -c ...`, it's a question of error handling.  For this specific command it would not matter, but in general it does; for example, try putting

```
ex -c '%s/this pattern is not in the file/replacement text/g | x' filename
```

in a script.  Contrast with the following:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/no matching lines/replacement/g' x | ex file
```

The first will hang and await input; the second will exit when EOF is received by the `ex` command, so the script will continue.  There are alternative workarounds, such as `s///e`, but they are not specified by POSIX.  I prefer using the portable form, which is shown above.

For the `g` command, there *must* be a newline at the end, and I prefer using `printf` to wrap the commands rather than embedding a newline in single quotes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `printf` and not `echo` or something like `ex -c COMMAND`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, yes.  I started to answer you in comments but it grew long, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks and +1! I knew about `printf` vs. `echo` (though I usually just prefer `echo` when the argument is hard-coded) but I haven't used `ex` extensively so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '
  s/C/&/2;t   # when 2nd C matches skip processing and print
  /C/d        # either one C or no C, so delete on C
'

sed -e '
   /C/!b     # no C, skip processing and print
   /C.*C/!d  # not(at least 2 C) => 1 C => delete
'

perl -lne 's/C/C/g == 1 or print'
```

Comment: Note that it assumes GNU `sed`, `t #...` would typically branch to the label called `#...` in most other `sed` implementations.

Comment: Even the `!b` is GNU sed since branch doesn't like anything except a label or a newline after it.

Comment: Yes, `b`, `t`, `:`, `}` (and `r file`, `w file`...) can't have a command after them on the same line. You can also use separate `-e` options.

Comment: Your perl option doesn't produce the correct output. I guess you forgot to add the `g` modifier.

Comment: @TomFenech You are correct. I am fixing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of options using perl.

Since you're only matching a single character, you can use `tr/C//` (a translate, with no replacements), to return the number of matches of `C`:

```
perl -lne 'print if tr/C// != 1' file
```

More generally, if you want to match a multi-character string or regular expression, then you can use this:

```
perl -lne 'print if (@m = /C/g) != 1' file
```

This assigns the matches of the regular expression `/C/g` to a list `@m` and prints lines when the length of that list is not `1`.

The `-i` switch can be added to edit "in-place".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting `awk` specifically, I'd offer

```
awk '/C[^C]*C/{next}//{print}'
```

skip the line if it matches the pattern, print it otherwise. You don't actually need `{print}`, you can use `//` and default print,  but I think it's clearer spelled out.

My first thought was to use `egrep -v` with the same pattern, but that doesn't actually answer the question as posed.

Comment: What's the point of matching anything after `{next}`? Just say `awk '/pattern/ {next} 1'` and all lines not matching the pattern will be printed. Or, better, `awk '!/pattern/'` to directly print those.

Comment: @fedorqui good point about `!/pattern/` (which somehow slipped my mind) but I'd far rather see a self-explanatory `//{print}` than a cryptic `1`. Assume the least competence and fluency from the next person to maintain your code, consistent with not making it seriously less efficient or effective.